# defining powershell function for python -m

Tags: python, powershell

i am trying to do something i thought is trivial

i just wanted to declare a function as that

```
function mds {
python -m "blabla" $args
}
```

but its just not working under powershell 
i got

```
mds : The term 'python -m os:String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
eck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

as i understand powershell takes whole python -m "asdfadsf" as command , but why and how can i workaround it ?

Comment: You're just trying to run a Python script from PowerShell? Is this not covered in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: yep, just wanted an short alias for something i run occasionally, no big deal, i am just surprised its soo obscure under windows

Comment: For instance you could be calling [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6).